# Symfony sending post request to log in, throws 401 error

Tags: symfony, guzzle

I'm trying to write a test that would send a post request to api using Guzzle and would try to log into the site and generate a JWT token. But it keeps failing with 401 authentication error.

That's how my code looks right now:

```
$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://127.0.0.1:8007/api/']);

$request = $client->request(
            'POST',
            'login_check',
            [
                'debug'=> true,
                'auth' => ['username', 'password']
            ]
        );
```

My routing.yml

```
login_check:
    path:     /login_check
    methods:  [POST]

secured:
    path:     /api/secured
    defaults:  { _controller: Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Tests\Functional\Bundle\Controller\TestController::securedAction }
    methods:  [GET]
```

And that's how the request payload is formatted, if I enter my log in data on the website.

```
{username: "username", password: "password"}
```

I think the problem might be caused by how I format username and password inside my request, but I'm not sure.

I also tried sending request using POSTMAN but got exact same results. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Please show us your security.yaml

Answer (score 2):

It was not working because I had to give the log in info in json format.

```
$request = $client->request(
            'POST',
            'login_check',
            [
                'json' => ['username'=>'username', 'password' => "password"]
            ]
        )
```